# Gif library for ruby/jruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby, gif, animated-gif

I'm wondering if there are any jruby libraries that support creating a gif pixel by pixel, like chunky_png. Pure ruby would be nice, but anything will do. Rubygems doesn't seem to have one.

I am aware of rmagick4j, but the library simply doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `rmagick`, which wraps the Image Magick library. It isn't specific to GIF, but it does support animated gifs.

Comment: You did say "anything will do" :-), although I understand Image Magick has a bit of an overhead (in terms of installation and complexity), that also means it often covers specific needs. There *might* be other options for GIFs in Ruby, so you could always hold out for a better answer.

Comment: Magick works great, except in jruby, which I'd like to use because of the cpu-intensive nature of pixel-by-pixel image generation. I might edit the question.